# Is there a way to implement a Spring Security authentication filter without database integration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jwt

I am currently working on a simple project using Java Spring.
And to implement the signup and login features (user authentication and authorization), I have created an authentication and authorization filter using Spring Security and JWT together.

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Not Found " + username));

        return new UserDetailsImpl(user);
    }
}
```

The above code is an implementation of UserDetailsService for implementing Spring Security.

However, I believe that sending queries to the database for user authentication contradicts one of the core characteristics of JWT, which is 'statelessness'. Therefore, I plan to refactor the code to allow the authentication process to occur without going through the UserDetailsService. In other words, my goal is to implement user authentication solely based on the user information contained in the JWT, without sending queries to the database.

Therefore, I have made comprehensive modifications to the code to enable authentication processing without using UserDetailsService. However, when I run the code and send an authentication request, queries are still sent to the database, even though my code does not use UserDetailsService. (It seems that due to the internal logic of Spring Security, it necessarily goes through UserDetailsService.)

Creating a custom filter for authentication and authorization processing without using Spring Security could solve the problem, but I am curious if there is a way to ensure JWT's statelessness while still using Spring Security.

Comment: To achieve stateless authentication with "JWT" in Spring Security, you need to configure Spring Security to validate "JWT" tokens and extract user information from them without querying a database on each request.So in short,you should create a custom authentication filter to handle "JWT" tokens.

Comment: There are no JWT filters in spring security because it is not recommended to use JWTs as sessions, or to even hand out JWTs to browsers. So my question is why are you building a custom non-recommended login that has several security issues and not implement one of the standards that come built into spring security?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Spring Security does.

First, you need to add some dependencies on your `pom.xml`.

```xml
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JWT -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.2</version> <!-- or whatever version you want -->
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- Other necessary dependencies (Spring Boot, Spring Data, etc...) -->
    <!-- ... -->
</dependencies>
```

The, Using a custom authentication provider.

```java
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationProvider extends AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider {
    // This should be an appropriate service which would fetch user data and perform JWT validation
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;

    @Autowired
    public JwtAuthenticationProvider(JwtUtil jwtUtil) {
        this.jwtUtil = jwtUtil;
    }

    @Override
    protected void additionalAuthenticationChecks(UserDetails userDetails, 
                                                  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) throws AuthenticationException {
        // Your additional authentication checks if needed
    }

    @Override
    protected UserDetails retrieveUser(String username, 
                                       UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) throws AuthenticationException {
        String token = (String) usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.getCredentials();
        String usernameFromToken = jwtUtil.getUsernameFromToken(token);
        return new User(usernameFromToken, "", new ArrayList<>());
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        return super.authenticate(authentication);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return (JwtAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication));
    }
}
```

In your security configuration file, you should inject `JwtAuthenticationProvider` into security's provider.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationProvider jwtAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authenticationProvider(jwtAuthenticationProvider)
            // Your other configurations
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/register");
    }

    // Your other configurations
}
```

Remember, this way you are really trusting the token, so make sure your tokens are secured and invalidated properly to prevent unauthorized access.

I only use this kind of authentication went I deal with internal API.